# Mongo does not read from primary when secondary is down

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

my mongo url config is `url = 'mongodb://1.1.1.1:27017,2.2.2.2:27017/test';`

where 1.1.1.1 is primary and 2.2.2.2 is secondary.

Initially it reads from the secondary but when I shut down secondary mongo does not read from primary and fails

I want to know how can I read from primary when secondary is down

I am using mongoose.

Answer (score 1):

In order for a primary to exist, the majority of voting nodes in the deployment must be available and communicating. If your deployment has a total of 2 nodes, and any node is unavailable, there is no primary.

> mongo does not read from primary

There is no primary in this case, therefore, it is impossible to "read from primary".